# Manipulating values of dynamically created objects?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have a javascript function which takes the values from JSON objects in an array, and creates/populates divs with an HTML template. When they are generated, they look like this on the page:

[dynamic objects elem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S8HI.png)

Each object that is created has four buttons that are cloned with it. When I click the "dam" button, I want to be able to affect the value of the object it is in. To further clarify with the following picture, if the purple button is clicked, I want to modify the purple value. If the yellow button is clicked, I want to modify the yellow value, and so on.

[colorized generated elems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioYdi.png)

Here is the template being cloned:

```
<template id="tracktemp">

  <div class="trackerItem">
    <div class="itemNameTextCont">
      <p class="itemNameText">Combatant Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHpTextCont">
      <h3 class="hpTextHeader">HP</h3>
      <p class="itemHpText">HP 100</p>
    </div>
    <div class="itemApTextCont">
      <h3 class="apTextHeader">AP</h3>
      <p class="itemApText">AP 30</p>
    </div>
    <div class="itemActionButtonsCont">
      <div class="actionButtonCont"><button class="actionButton">Heal</button></div>
      <div class="actionButtonCont"><button class="actionButton">Dam</button></div>
      <div class="actionButtonCont"><button class="actionButton">Stat</button></div>
      <div class="actionButtonCont"><button class="actionButton">Abil</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemModifyButtonsCont">
      <div class="modifyButtonCont"><button class="modifyButton">Edit</button></div>
      <div class="modifyButtonCont"><button class="modifyButton">Remove</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>
```

The area of the page it is cloning to (inside trackerCont Div):

```
<section class="trackerModule">
    <div class="trackerModuleCont">
      <div class="trackerHeaderCont">
        <h2 class="trackerHeader">Combatants</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="trackerTopButtonsCont">
        <div class="topButtonCont"><button class="topButton">Add</button></div>
        <div class="topButtonCont"><button class="topButton">Add From</button></div>
      </div>
      <div id="trackerCont" class="trackerCont">

        
      </div>
      <div class="trackerBottomButtonsCont">
        <div class="bottomButtonCont"></div>
        <div class="bottomButtonCont"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

And the JS doing the cloning.

```
var trackerArray = [
    {Name: "Joe Brown", HP: 100, AP: 30},
    {Name: "Steve Smith", HP: 100, AP: 30},
    {Name: "Jane", HP: 100, AP: 30}
]

function buildTracker() {
    var trackerLength = trackerArray.length;
    for (i = 0; i < trackerLength; i++) {
        var trackItemTemp = document.getElementById('tracktemp').content.cloneNode(true);
        var combatant = trackerArray[i];
        var itemParent = document.getElementById('trackerCont');
        trackItemTemp.querySelector('.itemNameText').innerText = combatant.Name;
        trackItemTemp.querySelector('.itemHpText').innerText = combatant.HP;
        trackItemTemp.querySelector('.itemApText').innerText = combatant.AP;
        itemParent.appendChild(trackItemTemp);
    }   

}
```

I was thinking I could use a for loop to change the ID of the button for each object, and then add an event listener, and go from there, but I'm clueless how to even do this. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Lot of thinks to explain...
general Idea is

- event delegation
- HTML5 data attributes + css pseudo element after
- I prefer DOMParser beside element cloning..

this kind of code

```js
const
  DomParser     = new DOMParser()
, trackerParent = document.getElementById('trackerCont')
, trackerArray  = 
  [ { name: 'Joe Brown',   hp:  80, ap: 50 } 
  , { name: 'Steve Smith', hp: 100, ap: 30 } 
  , { name: 'Jane',        hp:  90, ap: 70 } 
  ] 
function Add_Tracker(tracker)
  {
  let tackerHTML = `
  <div class="trackerItem" data-id="${tracker.id}">
    <div class="itemNameTextCont">
      <p class="itemNameText">${tracker.name}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHpTextCont">
      <h3>HP</h3>
      <p data-hp="${tracker.hp}"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="itemApTextCont">
      <h3>AP</h3>
      <p data-ap="${tracker.ap}"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="itemActionButtonsCont">
      <div class="actionButtonCont"><button class="actionButton" data-op="hp" data-val="+10" >Heal</button></div>
      <div class="actionButtonCont"><button class="actionButton" data-op="hp" data-val="-10" >Dam</button></div>
      <div class="actionButtonCont"><button class="actionButton" data-op="ap" data-val="+10" >Stat</button></div>
      <div class="actionButtonCont"><button class="actionButton" data-op="ap" data-val="-10" >Abil</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemModifyButtonsCont">
      <div class="modifyButtonCont"><button class="modifyButton"    > Edit </button></div>
      <div class="modifyButtonCont"><button class="modifyButton"    > Remove </button></div>
    </div>
  </div>`;

  let newTracker = (DomParser.parseFromString( tackerHTML, 'text/html')).body.firstChild
  newTracker.ref = tracker

  trackerParent.appendChild( newTracker )
  }

trackerArray.forEach(t=>Add_Tracker(t))  // builder

trackerParent.onclick = ({target}) =>   // or click eventListener (event delagation)
  {
  if (!target.matches('button[data-op')) return // ignore other clicks

  let Op         = target.dataset.op 
    , val        = parseInt(target.dataset.val)
    , trackerElm = target.closest('div.trackerItem') // .dataset.id
    , trackerId  = trackerElm.dataset.id
    , trackerOp  = trackerElm.querySelector(`p[data-${Op}]`)
    ;
  trackerOp.dataset[Op] = trackerElm.ref[Op] += val
  }
```

```css
* {
  font-family : Helvetica, Arial sans-serif;;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
.trackerModule {
  width            : 60em;
  background-color : whitesmoke; 
  margin           : 1em;
  }
.trackerModule h2 {
  width      : 100%; 
  text-align : center;
  padding    : 1em 0;
  }
.topButtonCont {
  float      : left;
  width      : 50%;
  text-align : center;
  }
.topButtonCont > button {
  width      : 16em;
  }
.trackerBottomButtonsCont {
  width : 100%;
}
#trackerCont {
  width : 100%;
}
#trackerCont > div {
  box-sizing : border-box;
  margin     : .7em;
  border     : 1px solid darkgray;
  padding    : .5em;
  width      : 31%;
  float      : left;
}
.itemHpTextCont,
.itemApTextCont {
  width      : 50%;
  float      : left;
  }
.itemHpTextCont h3,
.itemApTextCont h3 {
  margin-top : 0;
  text-align : center;
}
.itemHpTextCont p,
.itemApTextCont p {
  text-align : center;
}
p[data-hp]:after { content : attr(data-hp) }
p[data-ap]:after { content : attr(data-ap) }

.actionButtonCont {
  width      : 25%;
  float      : left;
  text-align : center;
  padding    : 0 0 .3em 0;
  }
.actionButtonCont > button {
  font-size : .8em;
  width     : 4.8em;
  }
.modifyButtonCont {
  width      : 50%;
  float      : left;
  text-align : center;
  padding    : 0 0 .3em 0;
  }
.modifyButtonCont > button {
  font-size : .9em;
  width     : 7em;
  }
```

```html
<section class="trackerModule">
  <h2>Combatants</h2>
  <div class="topButtonCont"><button class="topButton"> Add      </button></div>
  <div class="topButtonCont"><button class="topButton"> Add From </button></div>
  <div id="trackerCont"></div>

  <div class="trackerBottomButtonsCont"> &nbsp; </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @NickLeylandMedia I have made some improvements, but I have the feeling that my answer does not interest you, should I destroy it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't have time to properly review this until now!

I will admit this stuff is a bit above my level. I'll have to try an example of basic event delegation and DOMParser before I re-attempt this I think... I appreciate for the pointer in the correct direction!